# Testing logic where record's owner is inactive

Tags: apex, unit-test, user, ownership

I have a situation when an Opportunity is updated, but its owner is inactive. The record itself are fine. But I create a full duplicate of the Opportunity and change a few fields there (but not owner).
How to test this situation in Unit Tests?

I `runAs` Opportunity creation with active user. Then I set it to inactive by `user01.IsActive = false;`. Then I run update on Opportunity as another active user. But clone is created with owner, which should be inactive. It is in test method.
As I understand, Apex does not see that first user is not active anymore. It doesn't see it in triggers/classes.
While testing this manually I'm getting `INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER` error. But not in test.

Test method:

```
@isTest
static void closeWonInactiveOwnerOpportunity() {
  // ...

  Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='qqq'];
  User u01 = new User(Alias = 'aaa', Email='aaa@aaa.com',
    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='aaa', FirstName='aaa', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
    LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='aaa@aaa.com',
    IsActive = true
  );

  Opportunity contract01;
  System.runAs(u01) {
    // ...
    Account company01 = new Account(Name = 'bbb');
    insert company01;
    contract01 = new Opportunity(
      AccountId = company01.Id,
      // ...
    );
    insert contract01;
    // ...
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oliListToInsert = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    // ...
    insert oliListToInsert;
  }
  u01.IsActive = false;

  contract01 = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :contract01.Id];
  System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n\n --- Opportunity_IT - closeWonInactiveOwnerOpportunity - 1 --- \n'
    +'\n - u01: ' + u01
    +'\n - u01.Id: ' + u01.Id
    +'\n - u01.IsActive: ' + u01.IsActive
    +'\n - contract01: ' + contract01
    +'\n - contract01.OwnerId: ' + contract01.OwnerId
  +'\n\n');
  System.assertEquals(u01.Id, contract01.OwnerId);
  List<Opportunity> projects01 = [SELECT OwnerId, CreatedById FROM Opportunity WHERE Main_Opportunity__c = :contract01.Id];
  System.assertEquals(0, projects01.size());

  Profile p02 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='www'];
  User u02 = new User(Alias = 'bbb', Email='bbb@aaa.com',
    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='bbb', FirstName='bbb', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
    LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p02.Id,
    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='bbb@aaa.com',
    IsActive = true
  );

  Test.startTest();

  System.runAs(u02) {
    contract01.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    update contract01;

    List<Opportunity> projects01 = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE zzz__c = :contract01.Id];
    System.assertEquals(1, projects01.size());
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n\n --- Opportunity_IT - closeWonInactiveOwnerOpportunity - 2 --- \n'
      +'\n - u01: ' + u01
      +'\n - u01.Id: ' + u01.Id
      +'\n - u01.IsActive: ' + u01.IsActive
      +'\n - projects01: ' + projects01
      +'\n - projects01.OwnerId: ' + projects01[0].OwnerId
      +'\n - u02: ' + u02
      +'\n - u02.Id: ' + u02.Id
      +'\n - projects01.CreatedById: ' + projects01[0].CreatedById
    +'\n\n');
    System.assertEquals(u02.Id, projects01[0].OwnerId);
    System.assertEquals(u02.Id, projects01[0].CreatedById);
  }

  Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to **update** u01 after you make that inactive?

Comment: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 005g0000004YrSNAA0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): User, original object: Product2: []

Comment: Strange, but on `upsert u01;` I get `Error:(97, 5) DML not allowed on User` on class save.

Comment: Mixed dml means that you can not perform update DML on setup (aka user/role/group etc) and non setup (normal sObject) dml in same context. So, I suggest you next thing -- Create admin user, and 2 test users in @testSetup, then in test method, under runAs for admin user create account/opp records, assigned to user1, then disable user 1, then login as user2 and perform dml on previously created records

Comment: I managed the test by creating Opportunity in `@testSetup` and updating user in `@isTest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up separating creation of an Opportunity, which will then have inactive user and making user inactive and perform cloning of the Opportunity with inactive user. Creation is made in `@testSetup`, making user inactive and test itself are made in `@isTest`.

```
@IsTest
private class Opportunity_IT {

  static String CONTRACT_NAME = 'Contract 01';
  @testSetup
  static void testSetup() {
    // ...

    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='qqq'];
    User u01 = new User(Alias = 'aaa', Email='aaa@aaa.com',
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='aaa', FirstName='aaa', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='aaa@aaa.com',
      IsActive = true
    );

    Opportunity contract01;
    System.runAs(u01) {          
      Account company01 = new Account(Name = 'sss');
      insert company01;
      contract01 = new Opportunity(
        AccountId = company01.Id,
        // ...
      );
      insert contract01;

      List<OpportunityLineItem> oliListToInsert = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
      // ...
      insert oliListToInsert;
    }

    contract01 = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE :CONTRACT_NAME];
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n\n --- Opportunity_IT - closeWonInactiveOwnerOpportunity - 1 --- \n'
      +'\n - u01: ' + u01
      +'\n - u01.Id: ' + u01.Id
      +'\n - u01.IsActive: ' + u01.IsActive
      +'\n - contract01: ' + contract01
      +'\n - contract01.OwnerId: ' + contract01.OwnerId
      +'\n\n');
    System.assertEquals(u01.Id, contract01.OwnerId);
    List<Opportunity> projects01 = [SELECT OwnerId, CreatedById FROM Opportunity WHERE ddd__c = :contract01.Id];
    System.assertEquals(0, projects01.size());
  }

  @isTest
  static void closeWonInactiveOwnerOpportunity() {

    Profile p02 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='www'];
    User u02 = new User(Alias = 'bb', Email='bbb@aaa.com',
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='bb', FirstName='bb', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p02.Id,
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='bb@aaa.com',
      IsActive = true
    );

    Opportunity contract01 = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Name LIKE :CONTRACT_NAME];
    User u01 = new User(Id = contract01.OwnerId, IsActive = false);
    update u01;

    Test.startTest();

    System.runAs(u02) {
      contract01.StageName = 'Closed Won';
      update contract01;

      List<Opportunity> projects02 = [SELECT OwnerId, CreatedById FROM Opportunity WHERE Main_Opportunity__c = :contract01.Id];
      System.assertEquals(1, projects02.size());
      System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n\n --- Opportunity_IT - closeWonInactiveOwnerOpportunity - 2 --- \n'
        +'\n - u01: ' + u01
        +'\n - u01.Id: ' + u01.Id
        +'\n - u01.IsActive: ' + u01.IsActive
        +'\n - projects01: ' + projects02
        +'\n - projects01.OwnerId: ' + projects02[0].OwnerId
        +'\n - u02: ' + u02
        +'\n - u02.Id: ' + u02.Id
        +'\n - projects01.CreatedById: ' + projects02[0].CreatedById
        +'\n\n');
      System.assertEquals(u02.Id, projects02[0].OwnerId);
      System.assertEquals(u02.Id, projects02[0].CreatedById);
    }

    Test.stopTest();
  }
}
```